# Get the messages by id in the chat nebular UI

Tags: angular, nebular

i have Json file contains all the message that are stored in the database with the id of sender and reciver

- Json file :

[json screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZFh8.png)

So i want to display them in my chat By id user Like this photo

[Chat that i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPQsy.png)

this is method of all data :

```
getAllMessage()
{
  this.cr.getMessages().subscribe(res=>{
    this.allMess=res;

  })
}
```

this the HTML Part:

```
 <nb-chat [title]="recievername" size="large" [status]="theme">
      <nb-chat-message large
        *ngFor="let message of chatService.messages"
        [message]="message.text"
        [reply]="message.user.sendername"
        [sender]="message.user.recievername"
        [date]="message.date"
        [avatar]="message.user.avatar"
      ></nb-chat-message>
      <nb-chat-form (send)="sendMessage($event, avatar)" [showButton]="true">
      </nb-chat-form>
    </nb-chat>
```

**if i forget something tell me to add it**

Answer (score 0):

in "getAllMessage ()" function you're putting your data in "allMess" and when you tried to consume this data you called "chatService. messages" make sure this is not the mistake